# chartjs Show tooltip automatically

Tags: chart.js

I create charts for weather. I want to show automatically the tooltip on the last datapoint, when the chart is created. When the mouse is moved to another datapoint, the tootip should move to the new datapoint of the mouse or vanish if the mouse is outside.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/samples/advanced/programmatic-events.html ist very close. Thanks!

```
function triggerTooltip(chart) {
const tooltip = chart.tooltip; 
if (tooltip.getActiveElements().length > 0) 
  { tooltip.setActiveElements([], {x: 0, y: 0}); } 
  else { 
   const chartArea = chart.chartArea; 
   tooltip.setActiveElements([
      {
        datasetIndex: 0,
        index: 0,
      }, {
        datasetIndex: 1,
        index: 0,
      }], 
     { x: (chartArea.left + chartArea.right) / 2, 
       y: (chartArea.top + chartArea.bottom) / 2, }); 
    } 
chart.update(); }
```

I did expect that the index controlls the bar, for the tooltip. But it makes no difference, whatever Index is set.
Also when I change x,y it is still on the same place (close to 3rd bar).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVT7q.png)

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/samples/advanced/programmatic-events.html and https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.8.0/developers/api.html#setactiveelements-activeelements should help you realizing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api) in the `afterDatasetUpdate` hook as follows:

```
afterDatasetUpdate: chart => {
  if (!chart.tooltip.getActiveElements().length) {
    chart.tooltip.setActiveElements([{
      datasetIndex: 0,
      index: chart.data.datasets[0].data.length - 1
    }]);
    chart.update();
  }
}
```

Please take a look at the runnable code snippet below and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  plugins: [{
    afterDatasetUpdate: chart => {
      if (!chart.tooltip.getActiveElements().length) {
        chart.tooltip.setActiveElements([{
          datasetIndex: 0,
          index: chart.data.datasets[0].data.length - 1
        }]);
        chart.update();
      }
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Events',
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 68],
      borderColor: '#a00'
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="95"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for your code - I made an test.html see above, but there it is not working. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I copied the code again - and now it is working. I compared with my former code, but could not find any difference?! But it is working now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

thanks - it is exactly, what I am looking for!
The snippet in your answer works with visible tooltip on the last data point.
When I try it in test.html in my browser (I tested firefox, edge,chrome) the tooltip is not visible.
Where is the mistake in my test.html?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="95"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    new Chart('myChart', {
      type: 'line',
      plugins: [{
        afterDatasetUpdate: chart => {
          if (!chart.tooltip.getActiveElements().length) {
            chart.tooltip.setActiveElements([{
              datasetIndex: 0,
              index: chart.data.datasets[0].data.length - 1
            }]);
            chart.update();
          }
        }
      }],
      data: {
        labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
        datasets: [{
          label: '# of Events',
          data: [65, 59, 80, 20, 81, 56, 55, 68],
          borderColor: '#a00'
        }]
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

that is my test:

```
https://www.zebrafell.de/test.html
```

Comment: I had problems to select the items on the legend.
This was solved ny removing chart.update() .
It still worked..